# Override method of dll

Tags: c#, inheritance, overriding

I have a c# dll from a supplier. I have extracted the source code, but it's not an option to modify it myself.

Supose the dll has these classes (in the same namespace):

```
public static class A {
   public static string Method1(this Helper helper, B options) {
      ...
   }
}

public class B {
   public int LoadingElementDuration {
      get;
      set;
   }

   public string Method2() {
      ...
   }
}
```

Class A is all fine. This the class that is used by us.
Is it possible to modify class B? I want to add a property and override Method2 with my own code. Class A should then use my code instead of the default class B.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at the adapter-pattern.

Answer (score 3):

No, that's not possible because `Method2` is sealed. You could have written a derived class from B and added a new property but you cannot override `Method2`. This would have been possible if `Method2` was virtual.

Comment: Of course that it is sealed. class B doesn't implement any interface and the method is not marked with the virtual keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy all contents of this dll and paste it to a new created class library with the same class names. Then you can modify it as you want.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will only be able to extend the functionality and not change the existing.

Answer (score 0):

Why are this people saying that it is impossible? Am I missing something?
Make a derived class, add property, and use "new" to override method

```
public class C : B
{
    //add property here

    public new string Method2()
    {

    }
}
```

So let's take a look what we are getting here:

If you don't need to use added property in Method1 (this moment isn't so clear from your question):

```
C options = new C();
//init here
helper.Method1(options); //this will cast your object of C class to object of B class and your added property will be inaccessible.
```

But if you need to change implementation of Method1 to use your property you could try to do this way:

```
public static class CHelper
{
     public static string Method1(this Helper helper, C options)
     {

     }
}
```

and write your own implementation of Method1

Comment: And `Method1` won't call that because he accepts `B` as an argument and will ignore this pseudo-override.

Comment: How will it stop him from writing another extension method that using instance of his class as options?

Comment: Well, as far as I see OP wants class `A` to use his version of class `B`, without actually implementing all that code on his own.

Comment: I don't know all background, OP doesn't show it, but if you adding some property - you want to use it. If this property is going to be used in Method2 - there is no need to change Method1. If not - he should write his own implementation that using this new property, otherwise I don't see need to add it.

Comment: It's maybe beter to describe to backgound. the dll belongs to asp.net mvc. class A is AjaxExtensions and class B is AjaxOptions. I want to add a property to the ajaxoptions: private string _updateTargetSelector;  then I want to override the method 'ToUnobtrusiveHtmlAttributes'. So I ultimately can call AjaxLink with my new ajaxoption

Answer (score 0):

If the ClassA->Method1 is called from you code, all you need to do is extend ClassA and ClassB and add the methods that you need.

Comment: no, he said that he is using Class A. _Class A is all fine. This the class that is used by us_

Answer (score -1):

Create a new Class, inherited from ClassB, create a new Method2 with key word new, that's it